# What does the solution space of differential equation mean?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand what I am actually getting when I solve a differential equation. For example, the last one I solved was

$$y^\prime + y x \sin(x) = 0$$

and I got the solution

$$y(x) = C e^{x \cos(x)- \sin(x)}$$

I checked its graph on GeoGebra but what does it actually mean? How should I think about solutions for this kind of equation? I would like an intuitive explanation.

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct equation?

Comment: You think I made a mistake?

Comment: Well the equation you have written is just$$y'=-x\sin{(x)}\iff y=\int(-x\sin{(x)})\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: As stated yes.  Move everything over to RHS then IBP

Comment: Maybe you mean $y^\prime+yxsin(x)=0$ ?

Comment: Sorry I made spelling mistake now I fixed it, but my answer is not the issue here

Comment: Maybe look up slope fields.  Geogebra will do them for you I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each point $(x,y)$ you can compute $f'(x,y)=-xy\sin(x)$
For example $f'(1,1)=-1\times1\times \sin(1)$.  This means that the gradient of a line segment at $(1,1)$ should be plotted as approximately $-0.84$.  Can you see it sloping down?
[image]

Now imagine joining up all the little sticks.  You'd get a function such as the ones shown. Depending on which point you want included.
[image]

or
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: It is helps a lot thanks! just one question, if I understood you correctly, I can plot anyfunction that satisfy a specific set of slope lines? is it possible that $y$ is not continuos in specific points? because I imagine in my head a situation that $y \prime$ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation you are considering is an explizit first-order differential equation. The general form of this type of differential equation is $y^\prime=f(x,y)$, where $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function defined on some subset $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$. The following visualization of the function $f$ is then useful: consider a short line of slope $f(x,y)$ attached to every point $(x,y)\in D$ - the resulting geometric object is called a 'direction field'. Solving the differential equation $y^\prime=f(x,y)$ then means to find a differentiable function $y:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, such that the graph of $y$ lies in $D$ and fits to the direction field in the sense that at every point the slope of the tangent to the graph coincides with the slope prescribed by the direction field. Hence given a plot of the direction field in sufficiently high resolution and an initial value $(x_0,y_0)\in D$ through which the graph of the required solution is supposed to pass one can (almost) draw this graph by hand. In the example below four solutions and the direction field of a linear differential equation are shown; ; coordinates are $(t,x)$ instead of $(x,y)$ (sorry).

[image: Direction field and 4 solutions]